# DataGrab Incomplete Import

Tags: add-on, import, datagrab, addons

EE 5.3.0
DataGrab 3.0.3

Using the DataGrab add-on, when importing to channel entries I keep getting a 500 error and then a status of `RUNNING` on my imports with a `records` percentage.

[image]

[image]

This could become a problem because I'm going to be running one of these imports daily and it'll need to be updating ***all*** of the entries.

I've reached out to support directly but it's been a few days and I still haven't heard back. Wondering if anyone had any idea about this.

Thanks!

Comment: i'm experiencing the same

Comment: @JelleDijkstra have you tried batching your imports? I just played around with that and it worked great: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41671/datagrab-incomplete-import/41673#41673

Comment: I did. and that works partially. seeing a batched import of 25 take over 5 minutes per batch. same seems to be happening for member import

Answer (score 0):

So, a co-worker suggested I play with the `import in batches` setting in the `Other settings` section of the import configuration. I started with 300 and it did about 1500 entries before getting the 500 error, so I set it to 100 and it ran for a few minutes but got through all 4500 items completely.

[image]

I'm going to be setting my imports in batches from this point onward, and if you're having a similar problem I suggest you try batching your import as well.